# ActionBar exactly like Facebook app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere, holoeverywhere

I want to build a single-line action bar exactly like in fb, with tabs embedded inside the actionbar in form of icons at center so that when user swipes page the next icon is highlighted.

I'm using HoloEverywhere lib which uses actionbarsherlock internally. I'm aware of actionbar customviews but couldnt figure out how to embed tabs inside the customview.
Please help . If possible please share code sample

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: It's highly likely that Facebook is not using the system ActionBar.

Comment: This bar is not an ActionBar. Hide the ActionBar and implement your own Bar View.

Comment: @BraisGabin but then how do they syncronize page swipe with the icons, i mean if fragment is swiped , the respective icon is highligted

Comment: I don't know. They do all custom. All Facebook app is custom. Facebook is not a good example of Android Design. It's only a great example of Facebook Design.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an xml layout that looks like the Facebook action bar, then do something like this:

```
ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_header_xml, null);
action.setCustomView(view);
```

You just have to make the xml, then it should display fine.

Comment: Or maybe I don't get what you mean

Comment: what about swipe views, these icons react to it,  if i add viewpager using tabs i get an additional line of tabs below actionbar , so then how to hide tht entire bar